# OnClickListener not working with nested elements in Android view

Tags: android, xml

So I have a view with some nested layouts, I would like to be able to click the @+id/likeStar imageview. I know that my OnClickListener is correct because it worked untill I started adding nested layouts. What do I need to change to make the ImageView clickable again?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <!-- Title -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/CardTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="Title" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/likeStar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_important"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Stroke -->

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/stroke"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <!-- Card text -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/poster" />
        <!-- Fixed views (aligned to the left) -->


        <!-- Dynamic views (aligned to the right) -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardPlayDuration"
            style="@style/CardText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="126min" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardCategory"
            style="@style/CardText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/cardPlayDuration"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Action  Adventure  Sci-Fi" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardRating"
            style="@style/CardText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/cardCategory"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="7,9/10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardDirector"
            style="@style/CardText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/cardRating"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Jon Favreau" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="When wealthy industrialist Tony Stark is forced to build an armored suit after a life-threatening incident, he ultimately decides to use its technology to fight against evil."
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code

```
public class MovieCard extends Card {
private Context appContext;
private String movieTitle, duur, score, regiseur, descr, genre, imgurl;
private ImageView like;
private ImageView moviecover;


public MovieCard(Context context, String movieTitle, String duur, String score, String regiseur, String genre, String descr, String imgurl) {
    appContext = context;
    this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
    this.duur = duur;
    this.score = score;
    this.regiseur = regiseur;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.descr = descr;
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
}

@Override
public View getCardContent(Context context) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.moviecardlayout, null);

    moviecover = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView));

    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { imgurl });

    like = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.likeStar));

    like.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(appContext, "LOL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return false;
        }
    });
    like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(appContext, "LOL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_important_liked);
            SharedPreferences mPrefs= appContext.getSharedPreferences(appContext.getApplicationInfo().name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed=mPrefs.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ed.putString("myObjectKey", gson.toJson(this));
            ed.commit();
        }
    });
    // Set title
    TextView titleView = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
    titleView.setText(movieTitle);

    TextView duration = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardPlayDuration));
    duration.setText(duur);

    TextView imdbscore = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardRating));
    imdbscore.setText(score + "/10");

    TextView director = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardDirector));
    director.setText(regiseur);

    TextView gen = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardCategory));
    gen.setText(genre);

    TextView description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description));
    description.setText(descr);

    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean convert(View convertCardView) {
    return false;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        moviecover.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That is a crazy lookin layout. Sure you can't achieve what you are trying to do in a RelativeLayout or something?

Comment: I dont think it's possible to do it in just one RelativeLayout.

Comment: can you please share your activity/fragmentactivity code? Thank you

Comment: activity code included.

Comment: If its really a fragmentactivity or an activity then Change the following line 'like = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.likeStar));' to 'like = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.likeStar));'

Answer (score 0):

If its really a fragmentactivity or an activity then Change the following line

```
like = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.likeStar));
```

to

```
like = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.likeStar));
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad! The code for the listener is not inside an Activity but in a normal class so when I remove the "view" it sais cannot resolve method findViewById.

Comment: So just extend your class with an activity or a fragmentactivity and get it registered in your manifest. Hope it helps

Comment: Cant do that, let me sketch the app real quick. I have a main activity which has a CardUI in it. I have a class "MovieCard" which gets data from IMDB and fills in all the elements on the card, which is the layout I posted in my question) after that the MovieCard object gets inserted into the CardUI on the main layout. So I cant convert it to an activity.

Comment: So correct me If I am wrong but you are trying to create a clicklistener inside another class. And you are just passing a view to find a view through that. if thats the case then I want to see the code where you are getting the view. I am pretty sure there is something wrong there.

Comment: Can you try removing the focusableInTouchMode or turning its value to true.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is not in your layout. I assume that this layout goes as item inside listview and dataadapter is used, where in getView method you use onClick on inflated view which steals MotionEvent from children. Two ways to handle click - use onTouchEvent or more easier is to use onItemClick event provided by listview.

Comment: I tried using an OnTouchListener but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

could you please try in `getCardContent(Context context)` .
`view.invalidate();
return view;`

Comment: I tried to update the answer, but I am not sure it will not work, because invalidate() forces an update in a visible view... you can try as well , somewhere in your code where the view has already been shown... good luck